# Bash Script Doesn't run properly when closing the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, terminal, shell-script

following Bash Script runs properly when I execute the `exit` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $1" "$5" "$3" "$4}')
formattedUser=$(echo $user | tr -d '()')
finalData=$formattedUser" to "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" "$(date +"%H:%M")
logoutTime=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")":00"
startDate=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $3}')
startDateFinal=$(echo $startDate | tr '-' '/')
startTime=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $4}')
startTimeFinal=$startTime":00"
loginTime=$startDateFinal" "$startTimeFinal

function diff_seconds {
    var1=$(date "+%s" -d "$1");
    var2=$(date "+%s" -d "$2");
    period=$(( $var1 - $var2 ));
}

diff_seconds "$logoutTime" "$loginTime"
periodMins=$(echo $(( period / 60 )))
finalDataToLog=$finalData" "$periodMins
echo $finalDataToLog | tee -a /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.log
chmod 777 /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.log
```

I included above bash script in .bashrc.

```
trap /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.sh EXIT
```

You can see the output below.

```
amantha 192.168.1.36 2020-10-05 10:29 to 2020-10-05 10:31 2
```

1st field - user 2nd field - user ip 3rd field - logged in date 4th field - Logged in time 5th filed - "to" word 6th field - logged out date 7th Field - logged out time 8th field - time period

The issue is when i close terminal it doesn't work properly. Output:

```
to 2020-10-05 10:28 0
```

**My purpose of doing this to determine a user's logged in time and logged out time using ssh**. Do you have any solutuon? Above one is worked only for exit command. It doesn't work properly when I close terminal or Connection Failiure.

Comment: [`last(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html)

Comment: It's not helpful

Comment: In one of these sessions where you know it's going to print incomplete information, does `who am i` return what you expect? If not, that's your problem